# Check or select multiple items in checkbox/listbox by clicking a custom html element (code inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I want to bind a bunch of checkbox items or items in a listbox to a set of corresponding custom images, so that when I click or select multiple images, it selects or checks the corresponding listbox/checkbox item.

The example below, works only on a lsitbox, but it doesn't select multiple items. http://jsfiddle.net/tnkboy/hvfF9/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JQuery Dropdown Selection</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
body { background-color:#efefef; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:60px; }

h2 { background: url(1326911803_kteatime.png) no-repeat; line-height:38px; padding:0 0 0 50px; font-size:18px; color:#666; }

ul#customselect { margin:0; padding:0; display:block; height:auto; overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 20px 0 !important; }

ul#customselect li { float:left; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px 0 0; cursor:pointer; }

#customselect li a { width:60px; height:60px; padding: 5px; background:#FFF; float: left; border:6px solid #CCC; border-radius:12px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:#666; font-size:38px; letter-spacing:-2px; }

#frm_options { clear:both; display:block; }

#customselect li a span { display:block; font-size:11px; letter-spacing:0; }

.selected { border: 6px solid #4a7329 !important; color:#4a7329 !important; background:#dbeccd !important; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <h2>How do you take it?</h2>
  <ul id="customselect">
    <li><a href="1" class="link">0 <span>Sugar</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="2" class="link">1 <span>Sugar</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="3" class="link">2 <span>Sugars</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <select name="options" id="frm_options" multiple>
    <option value="Nothing Selected">Nothing Selected</option>
    <option value="1">No Sugar</option>
    <option value="2">1 Sugar</option>
    <option value="3">2 Sugars</option>
  </select>
  <div >
  <INPUT NAME="options" TYPE="CHECKBOX" value="1"> Option 1<BR>
  <INPUT NAME="options" TYPE="CHECKBOX" value="2"> Option 2<BR>
  <INPUT NAME="options" TYPE="CHECKBOX" value="3"> Option 3<BR>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.link').click(function() { 
            $('#frm_options').val($(this).attr('href')); 
            $('.link').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected'); 
            return false; 
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to select multiple items, see it here http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/hvfF9/1/

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.link').click(function() {
            elem = $('#frm_options [value='+$(this).attr('href')+']');
              if (elem.is(':selected')) {
                  elem.removeAttr('selected');
                  $(this).removeClass('selected');
              } else {
                  elem.attr('selected','true');
                  $(this).addClass('selected');
              }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
I added support for selecting/deselecting individual items on the list, see http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/hvfF9/2/

Added code below:

```
$('#frm_options option').on('mousedown', function() {
        elem = $('#customselect .link[href='+$(this).val()+']');
        if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            elem.removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('selected','true');
            elem.addClass('selected');
        }
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like deselecting doesn't work great on a listbox, that's why I tried to implement a solution using checkboxes. How do I tweak the code to make them work with checkboxes. Thanks

Comment: @Emmanuel I've just updated the fiddle to fix selecting/deselecting individual items from the list, see my updated answer above and let me know how it goes..

Comment: I think it actually deselects in code, however it doesn't reflect on the UI until you move your mouse over the listbox control. At least that's what I'm experiencing from my end. On the other hand how easy would it be to substitute the listbox with a bunch of checkboxes, what do you think? Thanks